# How to read JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, string

I have a JSON String and I got the `data` element's data to `JSONObject`. After I read this that resultant string is as follows. I'm using org.json library.

```
String dataStr = "[{\"name\":\"jhonny\",\"counts\":[\"50\",\"44\",\"46\"],\"url\":\"google\"},
 {\"name\":\"john\",\"counts\":[\"344\",\"4\",\"18\"],\"url\":\"yahoo\"}]";
```

I tried to read the each element like following,

```
String dataStr = report.get("data").toString();
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataStr.substring(1));
System.out.println(data);
```

But my output is,

```
{"name":"jhonny","counts":["50","44","46"],"url":"google"}
```

The output contains only one element. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is JSONObject? What library is it from? (The question is "How do I read JSON with *name of library*" rather than "How do I read JSON in Java")

Comment: (Also, did you know that whole string is a JSON array?)

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful. e.g. what is the value of `dataStr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(datastr);
for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject data= jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the  [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{interests : [{interestKey:Dogs}, {interestKey:Cats}]}");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
    list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to read JSONArray as JSONObject.

To parse JSONArray you need to do something like: (Not sure which library you are using)

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    // jsonobject holds the desired element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze your json string, you will notice that your json string contains multiple json object without outer object like :-

```
{ 
"outer":{
          {\"name\":\"jhonny\",\"counts\":[\"50\",\"44\",\"46\"],\"url\":\"google\"},
          {\"name\":\"jhonny\",\"counts\":[\"50\",\"44\",\"46\"],\"url\":\"google\"}
        }
}
```

The way you are parsing require this kind of json structure. Your json string is actually just a jsonarray. So do like this way :

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(datastr);
for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject data= jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

For more you can visit this link that gives you good explanation to [how to read json in java](http://codedestine.com/how-read-write-json-in-java)